# Why is my form data not saved in database?

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

When I fill out the form in Django 4.2.3 the data is not saved in database (sqlite3). I didn't use `{{ form }}` because option to hide fields based on selected options is not working.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

opciones_entrega = [
    (0, "Retiro en Tienda"),
    (1, "Reparto a domicilio")
]

opcion_retiro = [
    (2, "Retiro Local"),
    (3, "Retiro bodega")
]

class Reparto(models.Model):
    opcion_entrega = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=opciones_entrega, default="0")
    num_venta = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_venta = models.DateField()
    nombre_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    telefono = models.IntegerField()
    articulos = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    fecha_entrega = models.DateField()
    fecha_retiro = models.DateField()
    opcion_retiro = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=opcion_retiro, default="2")
    observacion = models.TextField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
return self.nombre_cliente
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Reparto

class RepartoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    opciones_entrega = [
        (0, "Retiro en Tienda"),
        (1, "Reparto a domicilio")
    ]

    opcion_retiro = [
        (2, "Retiro Local"),
        (3, "Retiro bodega")
    ]

    opcion_entrega = forms.ChoiceField(choices=opciones_entrega, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    opcion_retiro = forms.ChoiceField(choices=opcion_retiro, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Reparto
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'fecha_venta': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'fecha_entrega': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'fecha_retiro': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Reparto
from .forms import RepartoForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RepartoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('vista')  # Redirecciona a la vista de repartos
    else:
        form = RepartoForm()

    return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'form': form})

def vista(request):
    numero_venta = request.GET.get('numero_venta')
    if numero_venta:
        repartos = Reparto.objects.filter(num_venta=numero_venta)
    else:
        repartos = Reparto.objects.all()
    data = {
        'repartos': repartos
    }
    return render(request, 'app/vista.html', data)

def descargar_comprobante(request):
    numero_venta = request.GET.get('numero_venta')
    if numero_venta:
        repartos = Reparto.objects.filter(num_venta=numero_venta)
    else:
        repartos = Reparto.objects.none()

    contenido = ""
    for reparto in repartos:
        contenido += "Cliente: {}\nNúmero de Venta: {}\nFecha de Venta: {}\nTeléfono: {}\nDirección: {}\nArtículos: {}\nFecha de Entrega: {}\nFecha de Retiro: {}\nOpción de Entrega: {}\nOpción de Retiro: {}\nObservación: {}\n\n".format(
            reparto.nombre_cliente,
            reparto.num_venta,
            reparto.fecha_venta,
            reparto.telefono,
            reparto.direccion,
            reparto.articulos,
            reparto.fecha_entrega,
            reparto.fecha_retiro,
            reparto.get_opción_entrega_display(),
            reparto.get_opcion_retiro_display(),
            reparto.observacion
        )

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="comprobante.txt"'
    response.write(contenido)

    return response
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'app/base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}

<script>
    function mostrarCampos() {
        var opcionEntrega = document.querySelector('input[name="opción_entrega"]:checked').value;
        var opcionRetiro = document.querySelector('input[name="opcion_retiro"]:checked');
        var camposRetiro = document.getElementById("campos-retiro");
        var camposEntrega = document.getElementById("campos-entrega");
        var campoDireccion = document.getElementById("campo-direccion");

        if (opcionEntrega === "0") { // Retiro en tienda
            camposRetiro.style.display = "block";
            camposEntrega.style.display = "none";
            campoDireccion.style.display = "none";
        } else if (opcionEntrega === "1") { // Reparto a domicilio
            camposRetiro.style.display = "none";
            camposEntrega.style.display = "block";
            campoDireccion.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>

<section>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="text-center">FORMULARIO</h2>
                    <br>
                    <form action="{% url 'home' %}" class="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="opción_entrega" value="0" onchange="mostrarCampos()">
                            Retiro en tienda
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="opción_entrega" value="1" onchange="mostrarCampos()">
                            Reparto a domicilio
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <p>
                            <label for="num_venta">Número de Venta:</label>
                            <input type="number" id="num_venta" name="num_venta" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="fecha_venta">Fecha de Venta:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="fecha_venta" name="fecha_venta">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="nombre_cliente">Nombre Cliente:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="nombre_cliente" name="nombre_cliente" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="articulos">Artículos:</label>
                            <textarea id="articulos" name="articulos" required></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <div id="campos-retiro" style="display: none;">
                            <p>
                                <label for="opcion_retiro">Opción de Retiro:</label>
                                <select id="opcion_retiro" name="opcion_retiro">
                                    <option value="2">Retiro Local</option>
                                    <option value="3">Retiro Bodega</option>
                                </select>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="fecha_retiro">Fecha de Retiro:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="fecha_retiro" name="fecha_retiro">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="campos-entrega" style="display: none;">
                            <div id="campo-direccion" style="display: none;">
                                <p>
                                    <label for="dirección">Dirección:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="dirección" name="dirección">
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p>
                                <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="telefono" name="telefono">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <label for="fecha_entrega">Fecha de Entrega:</label>
                                <input type="date" id="fecha_entrega" name="fecha_entrega">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <label for="observaciones">Observaciones:</label>
                            <textarea id="observaciones" name="observaciones"></textarea>
                        </p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                            &nbsp;
                            <button type="reset" id="btnCancelar" class="btn btn-warning">Cancelar</button>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="{% url 'vista' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Ver</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <br>
                    {{ mensaje }}
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

I want the entered form data to be saved in database so I can visualize it.

Comment: I'm still looking at it, but it could just be this:  You have in your HTML `<input type="radio" name="opción_entrega" value="1" onchange="mostrarCampos()">` with `opción_entrega` with an accent mark, yet in the **forms.py** and **models.py** it is without an accent.  Are there any `form.errors`?

Comment: I'd imagine `form.is_valid()` returns False, but you don't have proper error handling in place so you never know.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the problem is in your input naming it does not match the model's field name

for example you have field named 'opcion_entrega':

```
opcion_entrega = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=opciones_entrega, default="0")
```

but you used 'opción_entrega' as name for your input:

```
<input type="radio" name="opción_entrega" value="0" onchange="mostrarCampos()">
```

it needs to be changed to:

```
<input type="radio" name="opcion_entrega" value="0" onchange="mostrarCampos()">
```

check your inputs names to match the model

I hope this helps you